# 3DS Max: Multiple subtraction (boolean) - how to do it?

Tags: 3d, 3ds-max

I have a board full of inputs, and need holes in the box behind them.

[image]

**How can I do these all at once instead of multiple boolean operations?**

Comment: Doing booleans on polygon models is a bad idea in general

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like the holes you need are evenly spaced. You could make one cylinder, create an array, group the cylinders together, then do the bolean operation with the group of cylinders and the board.

Comment: Hmm, maybe I missed something. I tried a similar way but boolean and pro boolean were grayed out. *Manually clicking each hole was taking massive resources - halfway through I had to stop.* Thanks for the answer - was starting to think this was where 3D questions came to die :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to place **Cylinders (6 sides)** in every hole using array or Manual method.

Then convert 1 **Cylinder into Editable poly**.

choose **Attach List** under Edit geometry(marked in red in the image).
**select all cylinders that are to be attached in the list**.(**Attach** -all attached objects will behave as  1 object now .Just like group)

[image]

Finally, all u have to do is use boolean or pro boolean to pick this 1 object.

Boolen or Pro boolean -

Select ur **box first** then choose ,

Boolen(make sure it is in subraction) -**"pick operand B"**

or

Pro boolean -  Click **"Start picking"** and pick ur cylinder.